# How to access arguments.callee in CoffeeScript class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have the following code

```coffeescript
class Foo 

  a: ->
    console.log arguments.callee.name

  b: ->
    @a()

  c: ->
    @a()


f = new Foo
f.b() #=> should output 'b'
f.c() #=> should output 'c'
```

#### Question: How can I get the name of the calling function in my class?

---

Here's a use case

```
class Something extends Stream

  foo: ->
    _helper 'foo', 'a', 'b', 'c'

  bar: ->
    _helper 'bar', 'my neighbor totoro'

  dim: ->
    _helper 'dim', 1, 2, 3

  sum: ->
    _helper 'sum', 'hello', 'world'

  _helper: (command, params...) ->
    @emit 'data', command, params...

something = new Something
something.foo()
something.bar()
# ...
```

I don't want to have to duplicate sending the method name for each call to my private `_helper` method

Comment: Do you have a good reason to? `arguments.callee` should generally be avoided and can't be used in strict code, which I believe CoffeeScript uses by default.

Comment: @minitech, `b` and `c` will be publicly accessible wrapper methods that gets passed along by `a` as an argument to another piece of my code. It would help to prevent a lot of duplication.

Comment: @naomik - Would you provide us the code for `a`, `b` and `c`. You can't access `arguments.callee`, but we may be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: This will ruin your performance, FYI. `arguments` kicks all modern VMs into interpreted mode, instead of JIT compilation to machine code.

Comment: @Domenic, so you are suggesting to just implement what i have in the use case (second code paste) ?

Comment: @naomik - Yes. It's cleaner, more descriptive and does what you want it to. You may also use `bind` to create those methods for you.

Comment: _"How can I get the name of the calling function?"_ Do you want the _calling_ function as per the question you put in bold, or the _called_ function as per your code with `arguments.callee`?

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear, I think the second way you have it is totally reasonable and is the way to go.

But to answer your question, you can generate each function dynamically to avoid having to retype the commands.

```
class Foo
  commands =
    foo: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    bar: ['my neighbor totoro']
    dim: [1,2,3]

  for own name, args of commands
    Foo::[name] = ->
      @emit 'data', name, args...
```

and assuming you want the functions to useful stuff, you can still use functions.

```
// ...
  commands =
    foo: (args...) -> return ['a', 'b', 'c']
    // ...

  for own name, cb of commands
    Foo::[name] = (command_args...) ->
      args = cb.apply @, command_args
      @emit 'data', name, args...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would have done:

```
class Something extends Stream
    constructor: ->
        @foo = helper.bind @, "foo", "a", "b", "c"
        @bar = helper.bind @, "bar", "my neighbor totoro"
        @dim = helper.bind @, "dim", 1, 2, 3
        @sum = helper.bind @, "sum", "hello", "world"

    helper = (command, params...) ->
        @emit 'data', command, params...
```

The advantages of this method are:

1. The `helper` function is a private variable. It can't be accessed directly via an instance.
2. The `helper` function is only declared once and is shared between all instances.
3. The functions `foo`, `bar`, `dim` and `sum` are [partial applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) of `helper`. Hence they don't consume more memory for the function body.
4. It doesn't require a loop like @loganfsmyth's answer does.
5. It's cleaner.

**Edit:** An even cleaner approach would be:

```
class Something extends Stream
    constructor: ->
        @foo = @emit.bind @, "data", "foo", "a", "b", "c"
        @bar = @emit.bind @, "data", "bar", "my neighbor totoro"
        @dim = @emit.bind @, "data", "dim", 1, 2, 3
        @sum = @emit.bind @, "data", "sum", "hello", "world"
```

Sure, it's a little redundant but you can't expect more from a language like JavaScript. It's not [Factor](http://factorcode.org/). However it is readable, clean, easily understandable, and above all - correct.

Comment: I beg to differ. You do need to bind during instantiation because `@` points to the constructor and not the instance of the constructor when the class is defined. Your [line converts to](http://tinyurl.com/cgla6nb) `Something.prototype.foo = Something.emit.bind(Something, "data", "foo", "a", "b", "c")` which is wrong. The `emit` method does not exist on `Something`. My [line correctly converts to](http://tinyurl.com/cmzwnxo) `this.foo = this.emit.bind(this, "data", "foo", "a", "b", "c")` where `this` points to the instance of `Something`. See the [class](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) docs.

Comment: Doh, yeah sorry, I obviously didn't fully think that through. Erasing my comment.

Comment: "The helper function is only declared once and is shared between all instances." This is false. Not only `helper`, but also `foo`, etc., are now instance members, not prototype members. Which means they will be re-created every single time the constructor is called, and new memory allocated for them every single time.

Comment: @Domenic - The `helper` function is neither an instance member nor a prototype member. It's a private variable declared outside the scope of the constructor. Hence there's only one `helper` function regardless of the number of instances. It's defined at the time of function definition: http://tinyurl.com/ccouhkg

Comment: @Domenic - The other functions `foo`, `bar`, `dim` and `sum` are partial applications of `helper`. Yes, each instance of the class will have it's own version of the functions. No, the functions are not re-created every time - memory is only allocated for the `this` pointer and the arguments which are partially applied to the `helper` function. A whole new function is not created. That's the reason I mentioned "Hence they don't consume more memory for the function body".

Comment: @AaditMShah sorry, but you are wrong. Run the memory profiler in Chrome and you will see the results. If a function body contains `function () { }`, then that contained function will be re-declared and re-allocated every time the outer function body is called. If that inner function is then stored on a member variable, like `foo` etc. are, then they will stay in memory until the containing instance gets garbage collected.

Comment: @Domenic - I understand your point - `constructor` is the outer function and when you create the properties `foo` etc. on the instance then they are created individually on each instance. However what I'm trying to say is that since when you create a new function using bind (like `helper.bind`) a [Bound Function Exotic Object](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-8.4.1) is created. These objects don't have the internal data properties of a normal function objects. Hence they occupy less space in memory. The point is that `bind` doesn't create a __whole new function__. Read!

Comment: @Domenic - The `bind` method can be easily recreated in JavaScript using `apply`. It's used to partially apply arguments to a function. The advantage of having a native `bind` method is that the interpreter can actually save memory by not having to create a whole new function. Instead we end up only having to store a reference to the bound target function, and the bound `this` pointer and arguments. That's the reason I said "__Hence they don't consume more memory for the function body__" in my third bullet point. Read my answer carefully. You're arguing about something else entirely.

Comment: @AaditMShah again, run the memory profiler and you will see. I am very familiar with the `bind` spec, but it still creates a new function with the most memory-consuming aspect---the `[[Scope]]` internal property---still intact. You have a misconception about how bound functions work if you think they "store a reference to the bound target function." See e.g. http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/v8natives.js?spec=svn10965&r=10965#1578 to get a look at how bound functions are *really* created.

Comment: @Domenic, I don't see where in the source code is a new `[[Scope]]` internal property created. On the other hand I do see it [storing a reference to the target function](http://tinyurl.com/cz28gxb). Why don't you have a look at the Rhino source code too? Here's the class for the [BoundFunction](http://tinyurl.com/clwbgep). Notice that it too does "store a reference to the bound target function". This is in accordance with the [spec](http://tinyurl.com/cm3ty6q) which says _"bound function objects do not have the internal data properties of ordinary function objects"_. This includes `[[Scope]]`.

Comment: @AaditMShah `[[Scope]]` is not an internal *data* property. It's implicit in the creation of the closure. I'm afraid I don't have more time to educate you here, at least not until you run the memory profiler and see for yourself. Once we have some actual hard data to argue, we can begin anew.

Comment: @Domenic - I did run the memory profiler, but I'm afraid I can't find the piece of information I need. Why don't you provide me a screenshot and explain what you're trying to say?